# Get image from Webpage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

What I am trying to do is to get image from that url
www.floraphotographs.com/showrandomiphonestuff.php?color=red&session=5345

The site displays a random image everytime , I need to be able to get the image in a NSImage object and display on the screen

Comment: You should add that the url above will return a JPEG image directly and is not an HTML page that *containts* an image. That's a difference. ;) (Just in case the URL might not be valid someday)

Answer (score 1):

Grab the data like so:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.flora...."];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Then stick it in a UIImage:

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Then put it in a UIImageView:

```
imageView.image = image;
```